# How to write complex query using criteria builder

Tags: jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Please help me to get the criteria builder version of following sql for the below given entity class:

sql:

```
select u.userid from employee e inner join user u on e.userid=u.userid 
inner join employee_project ep on ep.empId=e.empId 
inner join ep.projectId=p.projectId where p.projectId in (?,?...);
```

And also this should be able to used as a sub query too.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee")
public class Employee {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="Employee_Project",
            joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="empId", referencedColumnName="empId") },
            inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="prjId", referencedColumnName="prjId") }
    )

    private List<Project> project;

}
```

Comment: Start by writing it in JPQL. Than translating it to criteria, if really needed, will be much easier.

Comment: I have no way to write it as a JPQL because I need this part as a modification of an existing criteria query which need to be dynamically generated as it uses in a search page.

Comment: That shouldn't prevent you from writing it in JPQL first, in your preferred text editor, and to translate the JPQL query after. It's just part of the process.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It did work the way you told.